# Length of endogenous variable must be larger the the number of lags used

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I was recently following this tutorial  on Time Series Analysis in Python by Susan Li. I am fitting a time series SARIMAX model on the following series:

```py
y['2017':]

OUT: 
Order Date
2017-01-01     397.602133
2017-02-01     528.179800
2017-03-01     544.672240
2017-04-01     453.297905
2017-05-01     678.302328
2017-06-01     826.460291
2017-07-01     562.524857
2017-08-01     857.881889
2017-09-01    1209.508583
2017-10-01     875.362728
2017-11-01    1277.817759
2017-12-01    1256.298672
Freq: MS, Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

using the following:

```py
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=(1, 1, 1),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)

results = mod.fit()

print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

Now, this works well until here, but then when I try to visualize the results, I obtain the following error:

```py
results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(16, 8))
```

```
OUT: 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6cfeaa52b7c1> in <module>
----> 1 results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(16, 8))
      2 plt.show()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in plot_diagnostics(self, variable, lags, fig, figsize, truncate_endog_names)
   4282 
   4283         if resid.shape[0] < max(d, lags):
-> 4284             raise ValueError(
   4285                 "Length of endogenous variable must be larger the the number "
   4286                 "of lags used in the model and the number of observations "

ValueError: Length of endogenous variable must be larger the the number of lags used in the model and the number of observations burned in the log-likelihood calculation.

<Figure size 1152x576 with 0 Axes>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, if it's some kind of library error, and if it cannot directly fixed, then how can I obtain all the diagnostic plots?

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is not enough data to compute the diagnostic test statistics. What is the length of `y`?

Comment: y has 48 observations, so lenght is 48. Trying to replicate the same analysis, getting the same error, stuck at the same point

Answer (score 14):

While  defining the model, remove the parameter (enforce_stationarity = False ) and it should work fine !

Comment: I don't even know what it does, but it seems to have worked. Thanks a lot. Where can I know what is the use of it?

Answer (score 5):

For New people what Shantanu mean is -
Instead of this -

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                            enter code hereorder=(1, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)
```

You can write - *enforce_stationarity=False,* - this is removed, you can comment it as well - #enforce_stationarity=False,

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y, order=(1, 1, 1),
                            seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12),
                            enforce_invertibility=False)
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain why does it work?

Answer (score 1):

remove "enforce_stationarity=False" its working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this error in the ARIMA model, for some reason changing the figure size will fix your problem.like I did below:

results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(15, 12))
plt.show()

Comment: Do you have something in the training_X? this may happen if that's empty.